# Refreshing 3rd Party API Within a VBA Loop

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run a loop in VBA that will refresh the third party data, copy/paste the output as values, change the API period to an earlier date and run this on a loop. My issue, I think, is that VBA doesn't wait for the third party data to refresh before copy/pasting the next set of values. I'm using FactSet as the API and pulling some pretty simple data.

i = my relative date range. I start with -1 (equal to last month) and I want the loop to continue moving this month field back by one before restarting the refresh and copy/paste.

ExecuteExcel4Macro refreshes FDS codes for the whole workbook - this works fine.

The third group of code is supposed to wait until the FDS codes refresh, no longer throw errors, and copy/paste the output.

The i variable isn't changing, the FDS codes get refreshed too often, and the loop just copy/pastes the same data over and over.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate

i = ws.Range("E3")

Do While i > -5
    ws.Range("E3").Value = i - 1

ExecuteExcel4Macro "FDSFORCERECALC(FALSE)"

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("4:4"), "#DIV/0!") > 0 Then
    'Check every 3 seconds
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "Check_API"
    Else
        With Sheets("Sheet2")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End With

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows("4:4").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Rows(lastRow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
             xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

   End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?

```
i = ws.Range("E3")

Do While i > -5
    ws.Range("E3").Value = i - 1
```

It seems like your loop is never ending loop because your i variable is always the same

If you want decreasing counter, try to use:

```
i = ws.Range("E3")

Do While i > -5
  i = i - 1
    ws.Range("E3").Value = i
```